# I can't understand the callback reference in the recursion

Tags: node.js

Ok, sorry for the long code. This is a spider that downloads all the html pages from the site recursively. My question is: why the callback in the `iterate` function will always be this function:

```
(err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  console.log("All files downloaded");
}
```

which actually allows it to exit the recursion. I thought the callback would be like this, but of course it would create an infinite recursion:

```
(err) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      iterate(index + 1);
}
```

```
const request = require("request");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

function urlToFilename(url) {
  const parsedUrl = new URL(url);
  const hostname = parsedUrl.hostname;
  const pathname = parsedUrl.pathname;

  return pathname === "/"
    ? `${hostname.slice(0, hostname.lastIndexOf("."))}/${hostname.slice(
        0,
        hostname.lastIndexOf(".")
      )}.html`
    : `${hostname.slice(0, hostname.lastIndexOf("."))}/${pathname.slice(
        0,
        pathname.lastIndexOf(".")
      )}.html`;
}

function getPageLinks(url, body) {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const linkObjects = $("a");
  const links = [];
  const urlObj = new URL(url);
  linkObjects.each((i, elem) => {
    const link = $(elem).attr("href");

    try {
      const linkObj = new URL(link);
      if (linkObj.hostname === urlObj.hostname) {
        links.push(link);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // console.error(err);
    }
  });

  return links;
}

function saveFile(filename, contents, callback) {
  fs.mkdir(path.dirname(filename), { recursive: true }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    fs.writeFile(filename, contents, callback);
  });
}

function download(url, filename, callback) {
  console.log(`Downloading ${url}`);

  request(url, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    saveFile(filename, body, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      console.log(`Downloaded and saved: ${url}`);
      callback(null, body);
    });
  });
}

function spiderLinks(currentUrl, body, nesting, callback) {
  if (nesting === 0) {
    return process.nextTick(callback);
  }
  const links = getPageLinks(currentUrl, body);
  function iterate(index) {
    if (index === links.length) {
      return callback();
    }

    spiderNested(links[index], nesting - 1, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }
      iterate(index + 1);
    });
  }
  iterate(0);
}

function spiderNested(url, nesting, callback) {
  const filename = urlToFilename(url);
  fs.readFile(filename, "utf-8", (err, body) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code !== "ENOENT") {
        return callback(err);
      }

      return download(url, filename, (err, body) => {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }

        spiderLinks(url, body, nesting, callback);
      });
    }

    spiderLinks(url, body, nesting, callback);
  });
}

spiderNested(process.argv[2], 1, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

  console.log("All files downloaded");
});
```

Comment: *why the callback in the `iterate` function will always be this function* - I don't think it will. Try putting `console.log(callback.toString());` at the beginning of `iterate()`. Probably the resulting output will be tamer if you put it at the beginning of `spiderLinks()` though.

Comment: Perhaps I already understood. Then `iterate` is created, the first version of the callback is saved inside, and then when `iterate` is called, the reference remains as when creating

Comment: Every time `spiderLinks()` is called, its `callback` is captured in a "closure", which then the newly defined `iterate()` method uses. So as the recursion goes deeper, there will be multiple closures with multiple `iterate()` functions, using multiple `callback`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think that learning the closures thing should be enough, but here is a snippet showing how there are multiple variants of the `iterate()` function existing at the same time:

```js
function doSomething(callback) {
  function iterate() {
    console.log("This is iterate with callback", callback);
    if (callback) {
      console.log("Calling callback");
      callback();
    }
  }
  console.log("(1) callback is", callback);
  iterate();
  if (!callback) {
    console.log("Recursion here");
    doSomething(iterate);
    console.log("Back from recursion");
  }
  console.log("(2) callback is", callback);
  iterate();
}

doSomething();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

The most relevant part of the output is perhaps this one:

> ```
> This is iterate with callback  function iterate() {
>     console.log("This is iterate with callback", callback);
>     if (callback) {
>       console.log("Calling callback");
>       callback();
>     }
>   }
> -----------------------
> Calling callback
> -----------------------
> This is iterate with callback undefined
> ```

We are inside `iterate()` with a defined `callback`, and thus calling it, and it reports that it's `iterate()` with an `undefined` callback. It comes from the recursion parameter.
If you carefully go through the code and its output up to this point, I think you will understand the original code too.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `spiderLinks`, the recursion happens when it calls `spiderNested` to descend into the linked-to page:

```
spiderNested(links[index], nesting - 1, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }
  iterate(index + 1);
});
```

This is a different callback, so when that page has been dealt with, `iterate` is called so the next page will be similarly analysed.

Only the root of the recursion tree uses the callback that outputs the completion message.